# After installation of Drupal commons-7.x-3.13 in windows. I got this type of error?

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal Commons-7.x-3.13 module to install in windows. After installation I can't logged my site. [image]

Please help anybody. I am in critical situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate more memory. There is not enough for mysql to run. There is an entire handbook page dedicated to this common issue. See https://drupal.org/node/259580

Comment: Your answer is correct. It's worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `my.cnf` file.

In case of linux you need to use : vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Tweak/decrease these values as required.

```
wait_timeout = 600 
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

and restart mysql

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```